# Replace NULL and blank values in all Data Frame columns with the most frequent Non Null item of the respective columns

Tags: python, pandas

I am a novice to Python - I am trying to replace NULL and blank ('') values occurring in a column of a Pandas data frame with the most frequent item in that column. But I need to be able to do it for all columns and all rows of the data frame. I have written the following code - But it takes a lot of time to execute. Can you please help me optimize?

Thanks
Saptarshi

```
for column in df:
  #Get the value and frequency from the column
  tempDict = df[column].value_counts().to_dict()

  #pop the entries for 'NULL' and '?'
  tempDict.pop(b'NULL',None)
  tempDict.pop(b'?',None)

  #identify the max item of the remaining set
  maxItem = max(tempDict)

  #The next step is to replace all rows where '?' or 'null' appears with maxItem
  #df_test[column] = df_test[column].str.replace(b'NULL', maxItem)
  #df_test[column] = df_test[column].str.replace(b'?', maxItem)
  df[column][df[column] == b'NULL'] = maxItem
  df[column][df[column] == b'?'] = maxItem
```

Comment: What behavior do you want when there's no "most frequent" item (i.e. when all values are null, or when multiple items are tied)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`mode()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.mode.html) to find the most common value in each column:

```
for val in ['', 'NULL', '?']:
    df.replace(val, df.mode().iloc[0])
```

Because there may be multiple modal values, `mode()` returns a dataframe.  Using `.iloc[0]` takes first value from that dataframe.  You can use `fillna()` instead of `replace()` as @Wen does if you also want to convert `NaN` values.

Answer (score 0):

I create a sample data here.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [6,3,'null',4,4,2,'?'], 'col2': [6,3,2,'null','?',2,2]})
df.replace({'?':np.nan},inplace=True)
df.replace({'null':np.nan},inplace=True)
df.fillna(df.apply(lambda x : x.mode()[0]))

Out[98]: 
   col1  col2
0   6.0   6.0
1   3.0   3.0
2   4.0   2.0
3   4.0   2.0
4   4.0   2.0
5   2.0   2.0
6   4.0   2.0
```

Comment: Appreciate the detailed explanation - Thank you, this is really a great community